# Command to find source files for apt-get install locations - specifically libasound2-dev

Tags: debian, apt, bash, alsa, jessie-lite

Just downloaded and installed the `libasound2-dev` package using `apt-get install`

My gcc compile command now references `alsa/asound.h` correctly

But I just want to have a look at all the source files that were downloaded.

How do I find where they were installed?

I tried `sudo dpkg -L` for alsa and asound, but that was just an uneducated guess that failed. I imagine Debian installs these somewhere in /etc but I had no luck doing a manual search

There's probably some kind of ls / grep command that somebody knows off the top of their head? I'm very new at this Linux thing

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Jessie Lite installed

Answer (score 1):

The packages that you install with apt-get are download in the form of ".deb" files. The .deb files for packages you've already installed live in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. You could look for recently installed packages in there, with `ls -ltrc /var/cache/apt/archives`

Once you find the appropriate .deb file, you can list the files it contains (that is, the files that will/did get installed into the filesystem, vs. the various other control files in the .deb), like this:

```
dpkg-deb -c /var/cache/apt/archives/vim/libasound2-dev_1.0.28-1+rpi1_armhf.deb
```

You can also download .deb files for packages that are not installed, using, e.g. `apt-get download libasound2-dev`. This downloads to the current directory. I often combine this with `dbpkg-deb -c` to download some package into /tmp and check what it *would* install (say you're faced with several related packages, and you're really just after one binary that some script needs - you can figure out which of the several packages to install by downloading them all and listing their contents).

*Edited to add:*

You can get a copy of exactly what would have been installed like this:

```
cd /tmp
apt-get download libasound2-dev
ls -ltrc
# ls shows that apt-get downloaded "libasound2-dev_1.0.28-1+rpi1_armhf.deb")
mkdir foo
dpkg-deb -X libasound2-dev_1.0.28-1+rpi1_armhf.deb foo
ls -FR foo
```

At this point, you can peruse the contents of "foo" - compare the files there to what is currently installed in your system; check the names, lengths, timestamps, and checksums (md5sum is good, but cksum is sufficient for a sanity check), to see if what currently resides on your system matches a given package.

Comment: I've cleaned out the cache. I did find the libraries in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` - but not sure if there's a way to tell what version it is. Extension is .2.0.0 - that doesn't seem to match with the latest being 1.0.28

Comment: You might also try looking at `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log` and their older gzipped brethren to see what version of the package got installed,

Comment: (Added another suggestion to my original answer.)

Comment: What I really want is version numbers for installed packages - if I can find a match - I'll try grepping the history. Thanks